# Python script to build a C project in eclipse

Tags: python, c, eclipse, shell

I am trying to write a script which has to build a C project in eclipse.
I have tried the below script and it's not working.

```
import os
import sys

#*************Becoming a root user***************

euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:

    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)

os.chdir("/home/mymo/eclipse")

os.system("./eclipse --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -data /home/mymo/abhi/ENB_ws -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import /home/mymo/abhi/ENB/project_iss -build eNodeB_PHY/SO_creation -Ea PATH=/opt/intel/system_studio_2015.2.050/bin/intel64/")
```

So, Is there any other pythonic way to do this?
Also I am OK if it is possible with the shell scripting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this as root ? Why python and eclipse just to build C ?

Comment: Can you paste the traceback of python?

Comment: "any other pythonic way" - that's about as far from pythonic as possible...